# Check text for multiple RegEx matches

Tags: c#, regex, logical-operators

The code below reads in some text (scanned from an OCR library) a checks the text for a few simple words "the", "date", "or", "to", "and".... If it finds one of those words then this function returns true >>> meaning that the page it just scan was turned the correct way. If the function returns false, then the page is upside down and it moves to a function that rotates the page.

I'm just trying to figure out the best way to do this. I'm not a regex master, but the first if statement comes back true (so it finds 'date'). However, the second if statement comes back false even though i'm looking for 'date' again.

Do Conditional OR `||` not work with the regex?

```
static Boolean CheckIfPDFisTurnedRightWay(List<tessnet2.Word> wordList)
        {
            if (wordList.Count >= 70)
            {
                var text = wordList.Select(w => w.Confidence >= 40 ? w.Text : "DONTMATCH").Aggregate((x, y) => x + " " + y);
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, @"date", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    return false;
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, @"[trf]h[ec]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) | !Regex.IsMatch(text, @"date", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) || !Regex.IsMatch(text, @"[a0o][tfr]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) || !Regex.IsMatch(text, @"[ao]nd", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase) || !Regex.IsMatch(text, @"[frt][o0]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                    return false;                              
            }
                return true;           
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IsMatch` just returns a boolean, so you should be able to use `||`.

You may have a typo. Check out the single pipe between your first two `!Regex.IsMatch` statements:

```
if (!Regex.IsMatch(text, @"[trf]h[ec]", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    | !Regex.IsMatch(text, @"date", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    || ...
```

Also, if you only want to `return false` if none of the expressions in the second if statement are a match, you probably want to use the `&&` operator instead.

```
if ((text doesn't match 1st expression) and (text doesn't match 2nd expr) and ... )
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify/improve readability, you can evaluate different "or" expressions in a single Regex like this:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(@"(date|[trf]h[ec]|[a0o][tfr])", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```